# How to use the maxLik package to compute the MLEs

Tags: r, mle, error-messaging

I want to write an R-code to compute the MLEs of (µ; σ2; λ) with Newton-Raphson algorithm and try initial values λ = 0.5、....
I'm trying to run the following code in R, but I'm getting an error
I'm not sure what part of the formula is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
obs.loglik <- function(y, theta) {
  mu <- theta[1]
  sigma2 <- theta[2]
  lambda <- theta[3]
  n <- length(y)
  -0.5*n*log(2*pi) - 0.5*n*log(sigma2) - sum((y^lambda - 1)/lambda - mu)^2/(2*sigma2) + 
    (lambda - 1)*(sum(log(y)))
}

library(maxLik)

mle <- maxLik(obs.loglik, start=c(mean(y), var(y), 0.5))

# Error in fnOrig(theta, ...) : 
#   argument "theta" is missing, with no default```
````

Comment: You probably just forgot to specify y, already tried `maxLik(obs.loglik, start=c(mean(y), var(y), 0.5), y=y)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `theta` is fixed, we could use it as a global variable without directly providing as input.

```
obs.loglik <- function(y) {
  mu <- theta[1]
  sigma2 <- theta[2]
  lambda <- theta[3]
  n <- length(y)
  
  -0.5*n*log(2*pi) - 0.5*n*log(sigma2) - sum((y^lambda - 1)/lambda - mu)^2/(2*sigma2) + 
    (lambda - 1)*(sum(log(y)))
}

library(maxLik)

y <- 1:10 # example y
theta <- c(mean(y), var(y), 0.5) # Define theta outside

mle <- maxLik(obs.loglik, start=y)
```

If `theta` depends on `y`, we could do this instead.

```
obs.loglik <- function(y) {
  mu <- mean(y) # depends on input
  sigma2 <- var(y) # depends on input
  lambda <- theta[3]
  n <- length(y)

  -0.5*n*log(2*pi) - 0.5*n*log(sigma2) - sum((y^lambda - 1)/lambda - mu)^2/(2*sigma2) + 
    (lambda - 1)*(sum(log(y)))
}
```